# intck() giving negative value

Tags: date, sas

I am new to SAS and I am having trouble with finding the difference between 2 dates.
I have 2 columns: checkin_date and checkout_date
the dates are in mmddyy10. format (mm/dd/yyyy).

I have used the following code:

```
stay_days= intck('day', checkin_day, checkout_day);
```

I am getting the right values for dates in the same month but wrong values for days that are across 2 months. For example, the difference between 02/06/2014 and 02/11/2014 is 5. But the difference between 1/31/2014 and 2/13/2014 is -18 which is incorrect.

I have also simply tried to subtract them both:

```
stay_day = checkout_day - checkin_day;
```

I am getting the same result for that too.

My entire code:

```
    data hotel;
infile "XXXX\Hotel.dat";
input room_no num_guests checkin_month checkin_day checkin_year checkout_month checkout_day checkout_year internet_used $ days_used room_type $16. room_rate;
checkin_date = mdy(checkin_month,checkin_day,checkin_year);
informat checkin_date mmddyy.;
format checkin_date mmddyy10.;
checkout_date = mdy(checkout_month,checkout_day,checkout_year);
informat checkout_date mmddyy.;
format checkout_date mmddyy10.;
stay_day= intck('day', checkin_day, checkout_day);
```

Comment: How could you get `-18` instead of `-13` when comparing Jan31st to Feb13th?

Comment: It is probably subtracting 31 from 13.

Comment: You're doing something incorrectly - most likely referencing the incorrect variables in your code. Post the full code but it should work fine. Your dates need to be numeric variables with a date format applied. A datetime variable will also not work.

Comment: I have uploaded the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is a typo - using wrong variables in intck() function.  You are using variables "xxx_DAY" which is the DAY of month instead of the full DATE.  Change to `stay_day= intck('day', checkin_date, checkout_date);`

Answer (score 1):

Your data probably has the date values in the wrong variables. When using subtraction the order should be `ENDDATE - STARTDATE`. When using `INTNX()` function the order should be from STARTDATE to ENDDATE.  In either case if the value in the STARTDATE variable is AFTER the value in the ENDDATE variable then the difference will be a negative number.

Perhaps you need to clean the data?

The only way to get -18 comparing 2014-01-31 and 2014-02-13 would be if you extracted the day of the month and subtracted them.

```
diff3 = day(end) - day(start);
```

which would be the same as subtracting 31 from 13.

Example using your dates:

```
data check;
  input start end ;
  informat start end mmddyy.;
  format start end yymmdd10.;
  diff1=intck('day',start,end);
  diff2=end-start;
cards;
02/06/2014 02/11/2014
1/31/2014  2/13/2014 
;
```

Results:

```
Obs         start           end    diff1    diff2

 1     2014-02-06    2014-02-11       5        5
 2     2014-01-31    2014-02-13      13       13
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. the function intck() probably subtracts start from end. i.e end-start.
Also, using the same function, I am getting correct results for dates that are within the same month. I am not getting the correct results for dates in different months. Probably it is subtracting the day but not considering the month.
I have combined the year month and day variables using mdy() function. could that be causing the error?

Comment: To work with dates you need to have dates.  Your question made it appear that you had dates, but this comment makes it appear that instead you have separate year, month and day variables. You can use the MDY() function to convert those into an actual date value. Then you will have date values that you can compare.

Comment: I had separate variables for month, day and year. I used mdy() to get the checkout and checkin dates and stored them in separate columns. I passed these 2 columns as arguments to the intck function. I am still facing the same issue.

Comment: Update the question with example of the code you actually ran.